# configuring angular rest url with local host

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, rest, spring-boot

I have web application with Angular 8 and spring boot, deployed in EC2 using docker

The application is working fine if I use the public ip of the EC2 instance in the rest call

```
http://54.172.42.170:8080/test/getMessage
```

But it is failing if I use localhost in the rest url

```
http://localhost:8080/test/getMessage
```

**Error Message**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/test/getMessage' from origin 'http://54.172.42.170:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I want to use localhost so I don't need to change ip everytime the EC2 instance restarts

Comment: If you are using google chrome then you can try adding this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en and enable it. It will let you do the cross-origin calls

Comment: Are your angular app and spring boot app in separate ec2 instances?

Comment: No it's part of same war file

Comment: @kriti Thanks.if i disable chrome web security also it works, but asking all user to install plugin or disabling security is not possible

Comment: you cant localhost from a browser when your backend is deployed in the ec2 right. what do you mean you call localhost?

Comment: the rest call in the angular code uses localhost in the url  this.http.get(http://localhost:8080/test/getMessage). if i specify public ip of EC2  here then no issue in getting response

Comment: if i load your app on my browser it will never find localhost. I m trying to understand. answer is hooking up with a proxy config but i need to understand why the localhost? is it angular universal still it loads on a different machine on that machine it will never find localhost. why not hook up ec2 with a domain?

Answer (score 0):

An Angular application is running into a browser, so it **must** refer to the public IP or hostname of the backend. So you have to either:

- Get a static IP address
- Assign a hostname to the public IP

The error you observe mislead you, because you have a backend instance running on your computer. On a random user's browser, it would have simply failed with an error like ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: both are running on same server, same war file. i copied the output of angular build in to  springboot app's resource/META-INF/resources folder and created the war file

Comment: It is **served** by the same server but it **runs** into your browser

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your frontend is served from 54.172.42.170 and your backend is running on your local machine. Is this right?

You can configure your Spring Boot App that it allowes your origin 54.172.42.170 to access from cross origin. Like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://54.172.42.170:8080");
    }
}
```

You can find more information about CORS in the Spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html#cors